# What is the systematic name of a "double benzene"?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Consider the molecule representation below. What is the systematic name of that molecule?

[image: molecule]

Could it possibly be *3,4-hex-2,6-anebenzene*?

Comment: The commonly used name is naphthalene, the systematic name is bicyclo[4.4.0]deca-1,3,5,7,9-pentaene

Comment: According to current IUPAC recommendations (2013), the preferred IUPAC name (PIN) is naphthalene.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

[image]

Chemical Formula:

> $\ce{C10H8}$

Common Name:

> **Napthalene** (also accepted by IUPAC as per 1993 recommendations)

IUPAC Name: (refer numbering in figure)

> **Bicyclo[4.4.0]deca-1,3,5,7,9-pentaene** or **Bicyclo[4.4.0]deca-2,4,6,8,10-pentaene**

---

**For a general guideline:**

- Start with one of the bridgehead carbons and number it 1.
- Proceed round the longest chain of carbons to the second bridgehead.
- Number the second bridgehead carbon and continue on round the next longest chain of carbons back towards the first bridgehead carbon.
- Pass over the first bridgehead carbon (it already has the number 1) and along the shortest chain of carbons to the second bridgehead carbon again.
- The generic name for compounds such as this is

  > bicyclo[x.y.z]alkane
- where x, y, and z are the numbers of intervening carbons on the three paths between the two bridgehead carbons cited in decreasing numerical order, and alk refers to the total number of carbons in the ring systems.

Comment: Did you really mean to use equilibrium arrows instead of the resonance arrow?  Please read the other answers and comments to see why the usage of "pentene" is incorrect.

Comment: Numbering of atoms in picture is wrong and everyone can edit Wikipedia (well everyone with access to internet...)

Answer (score 2):

As @ron already said in his comment, the systematic name of the naphtalene is Bicyclo[4.4.0]deca-1,3,5,7,9-pentaene or Bicyclo[4.4.0]deca-2,4,6,8,10-pentaene since you can start the carbon numerotation from 2 chemically equivalent carbon.

You can find all the references [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naphthalene) and [here](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/)

Comment: I thought you always use the lowest possible numbering system.  It is not either or, or am I wrong? Is it really -pentene?  You don't see -tetrene used, it is always tetraene. Google "pentaene" and see how many molecules with 5 double bonds are returned.  I think -pentene is an error.

Comment: So you think it's pentaene ?

Comment: I do.  Look at this analogous example:  http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C2443461&Mask=4

Comment: Well, looks like you are right ;) I'll edit my answer then ! Thank you ron !